# Setting Vim to use shell syntax for dotfiles?

Tags: vim, alias, dot-files, syntax-highlighting

I am creating multiple files (`.school_aliases` and `.git_aliases`) to put my aliases in for organization. However, Vim doesn't highlight syntax for these files automatically like for `.bashrc` or `.bash_aliases`. Is there a way I could get Vim to do this automatically rather than just doing `set syntax=sh`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following in your `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.school_aliases,*.git_aliases set syntax=sh
```

Or, you can set these file extensions to syntax types in `~/.vim/filetype.vim`.

Comment: I changed `*.school_aliases` to `.*_aliases`, and it worked perfectly for all my alias files. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked out!

Answer (score 1):

Add to each of the files a line, thus:

```
# vim:syntax=sh filetype=sh
```

This line is a comment to your shell(s) (as it starts with `#`), but `vim` will see it and understand that it should interpret the file as a shell script for the purposes of syntax highlighting et cetera, even though the filename does not end with `.sh`.

Comment: This seems like it's working, but my color scheme doesn't apply as it would when I manually do `set syntax=sh`...

Comment: That's highly unusual.  You can set more things on that line if you wish to manually set the color scheme though (e. g. `colorscheme=darkblue`).

Answer (score 1):

Adding `.sh` to the end of the file name does the trick for me.

Rename `.mydotfile` to `.mydotfile.sh`